# How to validate a login page?

Tags: javascript

So far, this is the HTML login form that I've created and am attempting to add a validation form via javascript but there seems to be no actionable change with or without the javascript.
I wanted to turn it into a standard 'working' login form.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var un = document.loginform.usr.value;
  var pw = document.loginform.pword.value;
  var username = "username";
  var password = "password";
  if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
    return redirect() - > with('success', 'You are successfully logged in');
  } else {
    alert("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="loginform">
  <form id="contactForm" action="#" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    <i class="fas fa-user-alt" style="font-size: 70px; color: #96031A;"></i>
    <h2><strong>Login</strong></h2>
    <p>Login to your Vogue Account to access exclusive features. </p>


    <input id="email" name="user" class="txt" placeholder="Email*" type="text" required>

    <input id="password" name="pword" class="txt" placeholder="Password*" type="password" required>


  </form>
  <form>
    <aside>
      <label><input type="checkbox" />Remember Me</label>
      <aside>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="login-btn">
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="forget">Forgot Password?</a>
        <br>
        <input formaction="signup.html" type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="signup-btn">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Please define "_it doesn't really work_". What do you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: for one, your snippet is throwing errors

Comment: You've most likely got familiar with `getElementById`, use it, don't try to refer an element via `document` object directly, it's not there. How is the provided JS function even related to the provided HTML? There's no `#loginform` nor `usr` elements in the markup ..?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Try getting rid of `return validateForm()` from the `onSubmit` on your form, and instead try `<input type="button" onclick="validateForm()" value="Log In" class="login-btn">`

Comment: @MikeK That "wouldn't work" either, the submit listener is currently not  misplaced.

Comment: First, you should have a submit button.
Second, on form submit, you would validate your form and **prevent default** form submit behaviour.
Third, either cache your "username" and "password" DOM elements or fetch them inside your "validateForm" function with document.getElementyById method as @Teemu suggested.
Fourth, the **with** keyword is deprecated, don't use it. Take a look at the `window.location` object and use it for redirects.

Comment: You can't redirect from a submit handler function, the pending submission will prevent any redirection, unless the submission is cancelled (+ that line is a total blackout, whoever wrote it). When using an inline handler like you've used it, you can prevent the submission only by returning `false` from the handler, what ever else would be returned, the form will be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working as

you have login button in another form instead of the same form as the input fields.

Despite of that you are not taking values from the required fields.

You should try the below code which will work correctly.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var un = document.querySelector('#email').value;
  var pw = document.querySelector('#password').value;
  var username = "username";
  var password = "password";
  if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
    alert('You are successfully logged in');
  } else {
    alert("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="loginform">
  <form id="contactForm" action="#" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <i class="fas fa-user-alt" style="font-size: 70px; color: #96031A;"></i>
    <h2><strong>Login</strong></h2>
    <p>Login to your Vogue Account to access exclusive features. </p>


    <input id="email" name="user" class="txt" placeholder="Email*" type="text" required>

    <input id="password" name="pword" class="txt" placeholder="Password*" type="password" required>
    <aside>
      <label><input type="checkbox" />Remember Me</label>
      <aside>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="login-btn">
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="forget">Forgot Password?</a>
        <br>
        <input formaction="signup.html" type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="signup-btn">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Try to explain him why isn't his code working. He won't learn anything by giving him a solution directly.

Comment: yeah correct, answer has been added, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

the submit button must be in the same form with username and password field

```
<form id="contactForm" action="#" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    <i class="fas fa-user-alt" style="font-size: 70px; color: #96031A;"></i>
    <h2><strong>Login</strong></h2>
    <p>Login to your Vogue Account to access exclusive features. </p>


    <input id="email" name="user" class="txt" placeholder="Email*" type="text" required>

    <input id="password" name="pword" class="txt" placeholder="Password*" type="password" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="login-btn">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your function validateForm is never called. It is because your validation button is in a different form. Use only one form tag as below.

- Use document.getElementById
- close your aside tag

This code work a bit better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <script>
    function validateForm() {
        debugger;
        var un = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var username = "username";
        var password = "password";
        if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
            //do something here 
        } else {
            alert("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

<section class="loginform">
  <form id="contactForm" action="#" onSubmit="validateForm()" method="post">
    <i class="fas fa-user-alt" style="font-size: 70px; color: #96031A;"></i>
    <h2><strong>Login</strong></h2>
    <p>Login to your Vogue Account to access exclusive features. </p>

    <input id="email" name="user" class="txt" placeholder="Email*" type="text" required>

    <input id="password" name="pword" class="txt" placeholder="Password*" type="password" required>


    <aside>
      <label><input type="checkbox" />Remember Me</label>
    </aside>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="login-btn">
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="forget">Forgot Password?</a>
    <br>
    <input action="signup.html" type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="signup-btn">
  </form>
</section>
```